# Postfix + Saslauthd + Kerberos 5 + CentOS 7 not working

Tags: centos, postfix, kerberos, sasl, saslauthd

I've almost got saslauthd checking against Kerberos but seeing some last issues on CentOS 7. When postfix talks to saslauthd, it sends a lowercased domain and it's not corrected. I tried to fix things in /etc/krb5.conf using [domain_realms] but didn't work.  testsaslauthd works fine, as does kinit.

```
saslfinger - postfix Cyrus sasl configuration Mon Oct 13 02:09:37 EDT 2014
version: 1.0.2
mode: server-side SMTP AUTH

-- basics --
Postfix: 2.10.1
System: CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 

-- smtpd is linked to --
    libsasl2.so.3 => /lib64/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007fb849a49000)

-- active SMTP AUTH and TLS parameters for smtpd --
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = EXAMPLE.COM
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix-certs/smtp.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix-certs/smtp.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s


-- listing of /usr/lib64/sasl2 --
total 692
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Oct 12 20:39 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 62 root root 32768 Oct 12 15:59 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 19952 Jun 10 00:15 libanonymous.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 19952 Jun 10 00:15 libanonymous.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 19952 Jun 10 00:15 libanonymous.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 24160 Jun 10 00:15 libcrammd5.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 24160 Jun 10 00:15 libcrammd5.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 24160 Jun 10 00:15 libcrammd5.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 57888 Jun 10 00:15 libdigestmd5.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 57888 Jun 10 00:15 libdigestmd5.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 57888 Jun 10 00:15 libdigestmd5.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 36904 Jun 10 00:15 libgssapiv2.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 36904 Jun 10 00:15 libgssapiv2.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 36904 Jun 10 00:15 libgssapiv2.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 19984 Jun 10 00:15 liblogin.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 19984 Jun 10 00:15 liblogin.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 19984 Jun 10 00:15 liblogin.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 19984 Jun 10 00:15 libplain.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 19984 Jun 10 00:15 libplain.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 19984 Jun 10 00:15 libplain.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 28200 Jun 10 00:15 libsasldb.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 28200 Jun 10 00:15 libsasldb.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 28200 Jun 10 00:15 libsasldb.so.3.0.0

-- listing of /etc/sasl2 --
total 16
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   23 Oct 13 01:58 .
drwxr-xr-x. 98 root root 8192 Oct 13 00:42 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  101 Oct 13 01:58 smtpd.conf




-- content of /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf --
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: GSSAPI PLAIN LOGIN
keytab: /etc/postfix/smtp.keytab
loglevel: 6


-- active services in /etc/postfix/master.cf --
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache

-- mechanisms on localhost --

-- end of saslfinger output --
```

testsaslauthd:

```
[root@mail ~]# testsaslauthd -u brian@EXAMPLE.COM -p password -s smtp
0: OK "Success."
```

It very much seems like a problem in Postfix not sending the right parameters to saslauthd since testsaslauthd works.

**UPDATE**

On suggestion, have been using "ltrace -S" on a single-threaded instances of saslauthd and krb5kdc. When testsaslauthd is used, both saslauthd and the KDC have a flurry of activity and the result is a successful authentication, but when Postfix tries to process the same username and password, only saslauthd has any activity and the KDC has none. As well, there are no selinux audit logs.

ltrace -S output from saslauthd when called from Postfix:

```
**SNIP**
close@SYS(10)                                                                                                                                              = 0
gettimeofday@SYS(0x7ffffc0fa5b0, nil)                                                                                                                      = 0
<... krb5_init_context resumed> )                                                                                                                          = 0
__snprintf_chk(0x7ffffc0fafb0, 2048, 1, 2048)                                                                                                              = 33
krb5_parse_name(0x7f15647cc070, 0x7ffffc0fafb0, 0x7ffffc0fa6a8, 0x7fffffde)                                                                                = 0x96c73a86
krb5_free_context(0x7f15647cc070, 0, 0x7f1560ee5770, 0)                                                                                                    = 1361
__syslog_chk(3, 1, 0x7f1562b364cb, 0x7f15647cc060 <unfinished ...>
sendto@SYS(3, 0x7f15647cee20, 64, 0x4000)                                                                                                                  = 64
<... __syslog_chk resumed> )                                                                                                                               = 0
malloc(28)                                                                                                                                                 = 0x7f15647ce510
strlen("NO saslauthd internal error") Oct 19 14:21:57 mail saslauthd[32005]: auth_krb5: krb5_parse_name
**SNIP**
```

When called via testsaslauthd: Note the difference after the call to krb5_parse_name..

```
read(9, "smtp", 4)                                                                                                                                         = 4
__errno_location()                                                                                                                                         = 0x7fd8e86de7a0
read(9, "", 2)                                                                                                                                             = 2
krb5_init_context(0x7fffe69f1888, 0x7fffe69f4de0, 0x7fffe69f4ef0, 0x7fffe69f5000)                                                                          = 0
__snprintf_chk(0x7fffe69f21a0, 2048, 1, 2048)                                                                                                              = 19
krb5_parse_name(0x7fd8e8bfd070, 0x7fffe69f21a0, 0x7fffe69f1898, 0x7fffffec)                                                                                = 0
strcpy(0x7fffe69f19a0, "MEMORY:0")                                                                                                                         = 0x7fffe69f19a0
krb5_cc_resolve(0x7fd8e8bfd070, 0x7fffe69f19a0, 0x7fffe69f1890, 0x7fd8e870d0e2)                                                                            = 0
krb5_cc_initialize(0x7fd8e8bfd070, 0x7fd8e8c22090, 0x7fd8e8c21f70, 0)                                                                                      = 0
krb5_get_init_creds_opt_init(0x7fffe69f18d0, 0, 0, 0)                                                                                                      = 0
krb5_get_init_creds_opt_set_tkt_life(0x7fffe69f18d0, 900, 0, 0)                                                                                            = 0
krb5_get_init_creds_password(0x7fd8e8bfd070, 0x7fffe69f1920, 0x7fd8e8c21f70, 0x7fffe69f4de0
```

It very much seems that there's a problem with how the kerberos client library is being set up. Given that the KDC isn't even being called in the first case, it's as if the KRB5 client library is just rejecting the call as garbage and throwing everything out.  What I'm not sure of is how to figure out why short of compiling everything and attaching a debugger to it.

** UPDATE 2 **

Very close. The thing that finally got me going was to run saslauthd on the command line without ltrace, but with `KRB5_TRACE="/dev/stderr"` exported in the environment.  I noticed the following while playing with the testsaslauthd program (which worked consistently all the way through):

```
saslauthd[785] :do_auth         : auth success: [user=brian@EXAMPLE.COM] [service=smtp] [realm=] [mech=kerberos5]
```

That got me thinking, "hmm, that worked without a realm", so I removed the realms from everywhere, including the command line and the Postfix main.cf.  Everything started working.

THEN I REALIZED that I had set up the mail client with the username of brian@EXAMPLE.COM instead of brian@example.com. When I changed it back to a lowercase email address, everything stopped working.

THEN AFTER THAT I realized I had been using testsaslauthd with brian@EXAMPLE.COM.

Is this making sense? It seems like there is an issue with krb5.conf, but it all looks fine?

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 rdns = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 forwardable = yes
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
 EXAMPLE.COM = {
  kdc = mail.example.com:88
  master_kdc = mail.example.com:88
  admin_server = mail.example.com:749
  default_domain = example.com
  pkinit_anchors = FILE:/etc/ipa/ca.crt
 }

[domain_realm]
 .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Comment: i don't know what is the problem with your current configuration, but you can try to change your scheme: postfix -> saslauth -> pam -> kerberos

Comment: Yes, it is a little bit hard. I suggest to learn and use the strace, ltrace and lsof commands deeply.

Comment: Thanks guys, I commonly use strace and lsof, haven't considered ltrace. And going through PAM makes a bunch of sense. Thanks for the tips!